# How to remove hidden characters from a string read from excel file in Robot Framework

Tags: string, excel, robotframework

I have written a Robot UI test which is extracting some data from an excel file and compares them to what it got from UI. The problem is that in some cases, what the script reads from excel file has some hidden characters which cause a fail in the comparison. For example I have these tow strings (which I have printed their `repr`), first is obtained from UI elements and the second is derived from excel file:

```
1- 'u\\'Please fill back date...\\''
2- 'u\\'Please fill back date\\u2026\\''
```

Those hidden characters at the end of the second string fails the test case. How can I avoid it? I should mention that I have tried `strip` and it didn't help.

Comment: what characters are you calling "hidden"? `\u2026`? That is the unicode elipsis character. It's what microsoft will often convert `"..."` to with it's autocorrection function.

Comment: Completely right @BryanOakley, I've got this five minutes ago. Could you please write it as an answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hidden" characters that you mention are just the ascii representation of the unicode horizontal ellipsis. Some microsoft products (and perhaps some non-microsoft products) will autocorrect `...` into this character.